# How to downgrade firmware of Cisco Switch C3850 24T S

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I am looking for a way to downgrade my Cisco Switch's firmware from Cisco IOS XE 16.06.04 to 15.0. Is there a way to do that? I read posts that firmware downgrade can be done by TFTP server but I cannot find the correct image online. I cannot find any downloads from CISCO official website and it seems they intended to do this as they no longer support 15.0 IOS and force users to upfrade to 16.X. Despite that, I need to downgrade to 15.0 as my client server's switches all use 15.0 version and I need to match them.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the Switch's flash just to know if the old version is still there running the command

show flash:

or

dir flash:

if it is still there, you might continue with downgrade process.